# Landscape mode both side 180 degree

Tags: android, air, flash-cs3

I have developed a Flash game for Adobe Air.  In the game I set it to only allow the display to be in landscape mode.  If the device is rotated 180 degrees I want it to flip the view.  However, at no time do I want the display to allow portrait mode. How can I accomplish this?

## here is image you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the app to auto-rotate, and also prevent changes to portrait-aspect orientations.

See http://forums.adobe.com/message/3771984 for the details.